# How do I replicate these two effects in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, button

I am having trouble finding help on my own since I do not know the names of these effects. Here's the reference image:

[image: iamges]

1. How do I replicate the impressed circle effect behind the button? I
   tried playing with the **inner shadow** blending option with a
   **radial gradient**, but I failed to match the spherical depth shown in the image. I also tried using the **bevel and emboss** option,
   and while the produced effect is more accurate, I cannot duplicate
   the sharpness of the circle's edges, as well as the subtle highlight
   at its bottom. (I do not know how to add blending options to an
   emboss).
2. How do I reproduce the shape of the actual button in Photoshop? I've found tutorials on orb-like buttons and flat, raised ones, but the button in the image has a depth and shape that is a combination of the two. (Similar to a flat pebble).

If someone could lead to terms for these effects, that would be really helpful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a double gradient effect and added a very faint outerglow for the inner circle to give it some texture.

[image]

Comment: I upvoted yisela's answer since she answered both of my points, but I ended up using a combination of both of your suggested techniques. Thanks!

Comment: You can upvote more than 1 answer...lol

Comment: Oh, I meant accepted. I don't have enough rep to vote up right now..

Answer (score 2):

For the surrounding circle you can use two layers, one on top of the other, both with `Fill: 0%` and `Inner Shadow`:

[image]

- **Bkgr Layer 1** has a white inner shadow at -90 degrees (blend mode normal).
- **Bkgr Layer 2** has a black inner shadow at 90 degrees.
- **Button** has Bevel & Emboss and drop shadow.